# Please help translate these symbols from a very old bronze pot

Tags: translation

Please help translate these symbols from a very old bronze pot..

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Try asking Japanese SE

Comment: 東京 is not necessarily Tokyo.  東京 (Tokyo) is a relatively new name. The city was called 江戶 (Edo) before. There are also Chinese cities that were called 東京 during various dynasties.

Comment: looks like“东京住 寿親馬”

Comment: looks like 东京住 寿款道 to me